# Mocha testing in Electron project. Why is Babel needed?

Tags: javascript, electron, mocha.js, babeljs, chai

I have Electron project and wanted to implement unit tests. I installed `mocha` and `chai` but they fail to run because of the `import` keyword. I was wondering why, because I read that Electron does support ES6 and even ES7 for most things.

Here are my dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "mocha": "^6.2.2",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.12",
    "react-bootstrap-table-next": "^3.2.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.1.1",
    "react-splitter-layout": "^4.0.0"
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mocha and Chai is `devDependency`. It is not run on electron. When you bundle libraries for Electron. Only dependencies bundles up and run into electron, not the `devDependencies`. So while running mocha, chai test you need babel to support es6 syntax.

Comment: I think I understand. So, if not on electron where exactly am I running my tests?

Comment: node js, electron also has own node js. Pre compiled node js which can run javascript(es6). However, Your system may/may not run es6. That's is why you may need babel to trans compile js.

Comment: Are you saying that Electron has different nodejs? Can I upgrade global nodejs so it can run ES6, instead of installing Bable? What about `electron-mocha` ?

Comment: keep testing separate from electron. So that later in future you can upgrade test or electron with any issue. You can follow the steps here:
https://dev.to/bnorbertjs/my-nodejs-setup-mocha--chai-babel7-es6-43ei

Comment: One thing that bugs me is... mocha and chai are installed as `dependencies` not `devDependency`. Should uninstall them and install as `devDependencies`?

Comment: Yes.. Now its OK..webpack understand dev and normal dependencies. But previously, all the dependencies bundle to single file dev is not bundles. So safe..u should not use dev dependency as dependency. Normal install `npm i module-name` , dev deep: `npm i -D module-name`